# Django query with .order_by('title') doesn't give alphabetical order, sorts by date changed

Tags: python, database, django, sqlite

With the following model in my Django app:

```
class Story(models.Model):
#1:1 Fields
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    tagline = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    contents = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    full_length_book = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    publish_now = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField('date added to archive')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Stories"
        ordering = ['title']
```

I have several views that query the data from this model and use `.order_by('title')`, for example:

```
newlist = Story.objects.filter(tag=tag, publish_now=True).order_by('title')
```

The Problem: in the query results, as well as when I use the 'sort column' arrows in the django admin for the story group, it lists stories in order of last changed, and alphabetized within that ordering.  I need the stories ordered firstly and solely by title, alphabetically. Why does it put recently changed entries at the end of the list?

I may be misunderstanding something about SQLite- even when I go into the database manager and call `SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY LOWER(title)` , the order is still by update first and then alphabetically within that.

*edit* The SQL Django is calling is as follows:

```
'SELECT "app_story"."id", "app_story"."title", "app_story"."tagline", "app_story"."contents", "app_story"."updated", "app_story"."slug", "app_story"."full_length_book", "app_story"."publish_now", "app_story","date_added" FROM "app_story" ORDER BY "app_story"."title" ASC'
```

This looks like it should order by title, so I still don't know why the order is coming up with newly edited items on the end of the list.

Comment: You can execute `Story.objects.filter(tag=tag, publish_now=True).order_by('title').query.__str__()` to see underlying query.

Comment: Thanks!  I got the following: 'SELECT "arc_archives_story"."id", "arc_archives_story"."title", "arc_archives_story"."tagline", "arc_archives_story"."contents", "arc_archives_story"."updated", "arc_archives_story"."slug", "arc_archives_story"."full_length_book", "arc_archives_story"."publish_now", "arc_archives_story"."date_added" FROM "arc_archives_story" ORDER BY "arc_archives_story"."title" ASC'  ~This seems like it should work though, there must be something I misunderstand about the SQL